# Slot Machine Math

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

If we know (a),(b),(c) and (d) about a slot machine can we deduce (e),(f) and (g)?

(a) Theoretical Return to Player Percentage (TRTP) = 91.90 percent

(b) Progressive contribution from the TRTP = 3.19 percent

(c) Progressive jackpot reset value = 10,000.00

(d) Progressive jackpot meter increment (how much the meter increases with every dollar turnover) = 0.002

(e) Progressive jackpot odds = 313,479.6 to 1

(Working: 100 divided by 3.19 (i.e. ‘b’) multiplied by number of betting units in jackpot base value eg 10,000, betting one dollar per spin)

(f) Progressive jackpot meter after completing 1 cycle = 10,626.96

(Working: 313,479.6 x 0.002, plus 10,000)

(g) Expected Cost: 35,398 dollars

(Working: 91.90 - 3.19 - 0.002 = 88.708 (100 - 88.708 = 11.292) (11.292 / 3.19 = 3.5398) 3.5398 x 10,000 = 35,398)

Comment: ***^^^Bump^^^***

Comment: #probabilitytheorem